# eval javascript with a third party function

Tags: javascript

I am using dateFormat() function from a 3rd party lib.

The idea is to use the function inside a javascript expression and call eval(javascript)

the javascript is

```
var createDate = "11/20/2013 12:30";
dateFormat(createDate, "MM dd at hh:mm a");
```

this blows up saying dateFormat is not a function. How do I let eval know about dateFormat()?

the 3rd lib is included in the html page where this logic occurs (using GWT).

please don't offer advices to not use eval(). I have no choice here.

Comment: Are you sure there's a `dateFormat` function in the context that `eval` is called? What happen if you pass `console.log(dateFormat)` to `eval`?

Comment: no, I know there is not. that function is included in a js file which is declared in the containing page. my question is how to bring the function into the context for the eval.

Comment: Is `dateFormat` globally declared? What would you need to do to call `dateFormat` if you're not limited to `eval`?

Comment: yes, I can call dateFormat() with no problem outside of eval()

Comment: What would you get if you `eval("console.log(dateFormat)")`, `eval("console.log(window.dateFormat)")`?